# In Windows 10, how to choose save location

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu, save-as

I noticed on the PC of my father, who has recently upgraded the operating system to Windows 10, that the "Save as . . ." option is not part of the context menu (right click). He has only 4 choices in this menu, such as print, select all and two others I forgot. Is it possible to add the "Save As . . . " to this context menu (such as when you browse a page, or read an email).

I also noticed that if he decides to download anything, he is not allowed to choose the download location; it will automatically download in the "Downloads" folder. Again, with downloading, I am used to be given the choice where to download, much similar as with the "Save As . . ." Is this a setting that can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I can't re-create the context menu you describe, as I have save-as options when I click on text, images, or the page itself. What exactly are you right-clicking to get that 4-option context menu?

I am only familiar with Firefox and Chrome, but can give directions at least for those 2.

**Firefox:**

-click Tools and then Options (may have to press the Alt key to get Tools to show up)

-select the General tab, if not already there

-in the Downloads section, there's an option to always ask where to save

**Chrome:**

-select Settings from the main menu

-scroll to the bottom and click Show advanced settings

-scroll most the way to the bottom, and there should be a small Downloads section (it's right above HTTPS/SSL for me)

-check the box saying "Ask where to save each file"

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the browser you're using.

Chrome *has* an option to specify a default download  location, and another option to request a 'save-as' pop up every time.

I guess IE and Firefox have something similar.

Comment: Yes, all browsers have something similar. Opera has an option called "Ask where to save each file before downloading" right near the option where you can put the path of the downloaded files location.